# using a factory to create new objects in ValueInjecter

Tags: valueinjecter

When using the format...

```
var customerInput = Mapper.Map<CustomerInput>(customer);
```

A CustomerInput is created using Activator.CreateInstance.  I would think there should be a way to use a factory to create these objects.  So we would like to...

```
var customerInput = Mapper.Map<ICustomerInput>(customer);
```

...where we could use a factory to map ICustomerInput to a "new" CustomerInput.

Is there a way to do this with ValueInjecter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the "additional parameters" feature for this:

```
var customer = Mapper.Map<Customer>(foo, new Customer { ... });
```

you can use this parameter in AddMap like this:

```
Mapper.AddMap<Foo, Customer>((src, tag) =>
    {
        var res = (Customer)tag;
        res.InjectFrom(src);
        res.A = src.B + src.C; 

        ...
        return res;
    });
```